# Spring Social Facebook | Getting redirected to Signin Page after Authentication

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Folks,

First time I'm working with Facebook Social Integration. I was taking relevant code files from Spring.io samples and using it to build a minimalist 'Authenticate Using Facebook' application.

I am able to have the FB page open when I click on the 'Login Uisng FB' button. Upon entering my credentials (valid), I am again getting redirected to Signin page (/signin). What I am expecting was to get redirected to '/signup' which is not happening. I am looking to create a shadow account for the user using FB data.

Here is my configuration.

security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" authentication-failure-url="/signin?param.error=bad_credentials" />
        <!-- intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" /-->
        <!--  Spring Social Security authentication filter -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <custom-filter ref="socialAuthenticationFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="vais" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
        factory-method="noOpText" />

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder"
        factory-method="getInstance" />
</beans:beans>
```

Social.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config/application.properties" />

    <facebook:config app-id="${facebook.clientId}" app-secret="${facebook.clientSecret}" app-namespace="socialshowcase" />
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">

    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <social:jdbc-connection-repository/>    
    <bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

    <bean id="connectController" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController" autowire="constructor">

    </bean>

    <bean id="signInAdapter" class="com.mkyong.web.controller.SimpleSignInAdapter" autowire="constructor" />

    <bean id="disconnectController" class="org.springframework.social.facebook.web.DisconnectController" 
        c:_0-ref="usersConnectionRepository" c:_1="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
```

social-security.xml

```
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter"
        c:_0-ref="authenticationManager"
        c:_1-ref="userIdSource"
        c:_2-ref="usersConnectionRepository"
        c:_3-ref="connectionFactoryLocator"
        p:signupUrl="/signup"
         /> <!-- TODO: Figure out how to wire this without this name -->
```

Here is how try and setup FB login in my JSP:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK SIGNIN -->
    <p><a href="<c:url value="/auth/facebook"/>"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/social/facebook/sign-in-with-facebook.png"/>" border="0"/></a><br/></p>
```

I want that after successful login using facebook, the user should get redirected to 'signup' instead of 'signin' which is happening right now. 
Would appreciate any inputs.